# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name working in Default.cs but not Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

in my ASP.NET-app I'm using windows auth as only auth method.

I can read logged in user in default.cs:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Now, after inserting more pages to my app, there is a need of reading username at every page.

So I fired it in Global.asax, but the result is NULL.

My web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
         <authorization>
             <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

-pic

Comment: Where exactly in Global.asax are you trying to get user name?

Answer (score 1):

You use can `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` or you can set current thread principal in `Application_BeginRequest()`